# Relationship between label and readability in assembler

Tags: assembly, mips, readability

Using simulator Mars, I am programming in assembly for MIPS architecture.
At some point, I began to use labels that I don't even jump back to. 
I did this because I thought this may improve readability of my program.
Am I overusing labels? Maybe commenting is largely enough...
I'd like to know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I overusing labels?

Definitely yes!

Labels are only there for the assembler and not for readability!

Use comments instead.

Comment: Depending on how your debugger shows labels when single-stepping, it could make sense to put a label on a block just so `gdb` shows you're in a separate block when you step across the boundary, if you're using a disassembly view instead of source lines.  Especially if your branch-target local labels aren't at the logical boundaries between blocks that do different things.  (e.g. conditional branch over an instruction that isn't the last in a related block).  Still, for other people to read the code it's confusing because it makes them look for a reference to that label, so don't do it.